# # or (channel, height, width) but original PIL image has format (width, height, channel)

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, keras, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to run a image classification code using keras model.
I'm getting the following error while executing the code in jupyter notebook. Whereas if i execute the same code in google colab, it gets executed just fine.
I've tried solving the issue for a lot time and can't get a specific solution. Can anybody help?

```
img_width = 150
img_height = 150

train_data_dir = 'C:\PetImages'
validation_data_dir = 'C:\PetImages'
train_samples = 120
validation_samples = 30
epochs = 5
batch_size = 20

# Check for TensorFlow or Thieno
if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)


train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

X_train, y_train = next(train_generator)
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-198307faa4e0> in <module>
----> 1 X_train, y_train = next(train_generator)

~\.conda\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\iterator.py in __next__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    102 
    103     def __next__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 104         return self.next(*args, **kwargs)
    105 
    106     def next(self):

~\.conda\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\iterator.py in next(self)
    114         # The transformation of images is not under thread lock
    115         # so it can be done in parallel
--> 116         return self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)
    117 
    118     def _get_batches_of_transformed_samples(self, index_array):

~\.conda\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\iterator.py in _get_batches_of_transformed_samples(self, index_array)
    229                            target_size=self.target_size,
    230                            interpolation=self.interpolation)
--> 231             x = img_to_array(img, data_format=self.data_format)
    232             # Pillow images should be closed after `load_img`,
    233             # but not PIL images.

~\.conda\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\utils.py in img_to_array(img, data_format, dtype)
    307     # or (channel, height, width)
    308     # but original PIL image has format (width, height, channel)
--> 309     x = np.asarray(img, dtype=dtype)
    310     if len(x.shape) == 3:
    311         if data_format == 'channels_first':

TypeError: __array__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: What is the version of `PIL` you are using?